# jQuery fetch, store and use the class of child elements from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

Using jQuery the child elements of the `#parent` element are to be fetched with class `.west` and here not the content is needed to be fetched but the class of the child element with class `.west`

**Example**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child1 west"></div>
  <div class="child2 west"></div>
  <div class="child3 west"></div>
  <div class="child4 west"></div>
  <div class="child5 west"></div>
  <div class="child6"></div>
  <div class="child7"></div>
  <div class="child8"></div>
  <div class="child9"></div>
</div>
```

the result would be:

*child1, child2, child3, child4, child5*
and further they are to be used for example the css of child1 is to be changed using jQuery.

I really don't know how to use Arrays in jQuery.
Thanks

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/FVDgD/

Comment: @3nigma Actually good try but I want child1, child2...child5 as a class not text which would further be used for customization.

Comment: This is not clear what you want, you say *the result would be child1, child2, child3, ...* but then you say want them as *class not text*, in another place your talking of an array, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the classes of the elements in an array, you can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like so:

```
var classArr = $('#parent > .west').map(function(){
    return this.className.match(/\bchild\d\b/)[0];
}).get();
```

The regex matches any word that starts with `child` plus a single numerical digit. Modifying the class can be done using the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) function:

```
$('#parent > .west').attr('class', function(index, value){
    var currentClass = value.match(/\bchild\d\b/)[0];
    return this.className.replace(currentClass, currentClass.replace(/\d/, '10'));
});
```

Please look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) carefully and [play around with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/qmGjm/) to get a feel of how these pieces of code work.

Comment: I don't get the use of second part..It's just not clear. All I want to do is fetch the class and after that fetch the `background-image` from the css of that class. Further use that `background-image` URL.